# GIT status shows no midification but VSTS build fails with update remote error

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a GIT stream and issued following command -

```
$git submodule update --remote --force
Submodule path 'src/module1': checked out 'b6bbe051d27f84e52378'
.........................................
```

But when I issue below command I see nothing to commit:

```
$ git status
On branch feature/featurename
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/featurename'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Cause of this when I push my stream to VSTS - our VSTS build scripts marks the build as failed stating

```
Submodules need to be updated to HEAD to deliver to develop. Update all submodules
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Is that error coming from an in-house script? I've never seen an error like that before. If it is, talk to the person responsible for maintaining that script.

Comment: That's weird.If submodule has been updated, `git status` will show the changes. Did you execute `git status` in the main repo's directory (not the submodule's directory)? And `feature/featurename` is the branch in your main repo, can you also show the connect of `.gitmodules` file?

Comment: The issue got resolved when I rebased the stream